# Evitar la edición manual de parámetros de la URL en PHP

Tags: php, html

Como se evita que se modifique manualmente la dirección de la url en php por ejemplo para ingresar como administrador a un formulario ingreso con la direccíon http://localhost/SysCPC/document.php pero si es un usuario solo de registro ingresa con la direccion http://localhost/SysCPC/document_Reg.php, pero si le quita a la dirección _Reg entonces puede ingresar al principal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedes evitar que el usuario entre a esa Url, pero puedes controlar que va a ver cada persona dependiendo quien entre, para esto necesitarías hacer un inicio de sesión o algo parecido y solo mostrárselo a los usuarios logueados con permisos de administrador.

Comment: Eso lo hago pero si modifica la url manualmente si puede entrar, en ese caso ya que como dices no se puede, sabes si hay manera entonces de bloquearla para que no la puedan modificar o editar?

Comment: Hola buenos días, esto lo estas haciendo con php desde cero o estas usando algún framework.  Si es con php desde cero puedes hacer un redirect en la cabecera del fichero donde determines si no es del tipo administrador no puede entrar a esa pagina y te redireccione al inicio del cliente.

Comment: te recomiendes que estudies sobre enrutamiento con php , aqui te dejo un enlace por si quieres leerlo http://www.weblantropia.com/2016/07/28/enrutamiento-urls-htaccess-php/

Comment: La url a la que se dirigen es parte del navegador, no de tu aplicación, solo muestrales un 404 cuando llegen a esa página

Comment: Busca información sobre listas de control de acceso (_ACL_). Mediante inicio de sesión y asignación de roles, recursos y privilegios controlas eso perfectamente.